# ArgumentException thrown from ConfigurationConverterBase.ConvertFrom is escaping try/catch

Tags: c#, configuration, typeconverter, configurationsection

I've created a custom ***ConfigurationSection*** that includes an IP address value.  To properly get the value out of the configuration file a ***TypeConverter*** was created to parse the IP address.  The configuration file used for this test is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="mike" type="CustomConfigSection.SiteConfig, CustomConfigSection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </configSections>
    <mike IPAddress="192.168.0.1a" />
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

The ***IPAddressConverter*** uses a try/catch to determine if an invalid IP address was provided and couldn't be parsed.  At that point an ***ArgumentException*** is thrown.  Within the ***Open()*** method there is a try/catch surrounding the ***if (config.Sections["mike"] == null)***.  This is the first place the configuration section is parsed and the ***IPAddressConverter*** tries to convert the configuration value.

The issue is Visual Studio claims the ***ArgumentException*** isn't handled in user code.  According to the call stack, though, the exception is being thrown right at the beginning of the try block within the ***Open()*** method.

Does anyone know what is going on here?  Why isn't the catch within the ***Open()*** method getting the ***ArgumentException***?

Thank for the help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CustomConfigSection
{
    public sealed class IPAddressConverter : ConfigurationConverterBase
    {
        public IPAddressConverter() { }

        public override object ConvertFrom(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            string ipaddress = ((string)value).ToLower();

            try
            {
                return IPAddress.Parse(ipaddress);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The IPAddress contained invalid data.  The IPAddress provided was '" + ipaddress + "'.");
            }
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class SiteConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        private SiteConfig() { }

        #region Public Methods
        public static SiteConfig Open()
        {
            if ((object)instance == null)
            {
                Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

                try
                {
                    if (config.Sections["mike"] == null)
                    {
                        instance = new SiteConfig();
                        config.Sections.Add("mike", instance);
                        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                    }
                    else
                        instance = (SiteConfig)config.Sections["mike"];
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                    System.Environment.Exit(-1);
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Properties
        [ConfigurationProperty("IPAddress")]
        [TypeConverter(typeof(IPAddressConverter))]
        public IPAddress IPAddress
        {
            get { return (IPAddress)this["IPAddress"]; }
            set { this["IPAddress"] = value; }
        }
        #endregion Properties

        private static SiteConfig instance = null;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Before Open.");
            SiteConfig hi = SiteConfig.Open();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After Open.");

            hi.IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you are not accessing the property per se, the app still parses the entire section before making it available. The parsing occurs at 'config.Sections["mike"]'. However, the exception would bubble up only when you access the IPAddress property. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @StfBln "the exception would bubble up only when you access the IPAddress property" this doesn't seem to be the case.  I added a try/catch around the ***SiteConfig.Open()*** and added a try/catch to a new line to access the IPAddress.  The exception is occurring during the ***SiteConfig.Open***.  It doesn't "bubble up" when access the IPAddress.  Even the VisualStudio editor call stack is saying the exception is happening within the ***SiteConfig.Open*** at ***config.Section["mike"]***. When you ran the code were you finding the exception occurring at at different place?

Comment: What I meant is that this exception is silent as it does not bubble up. However, try to access IPAddress after getting your config as in: "SiteConfig hi = SiteConfig.Open(); var test = hi.IPAddress;" Now you will get the exception.

Comment: @StfBln The exception isn't silent.  I've commented out everything in main except the ***SiteConfig hi = SiteConfig.Open()***. It fails on this method call. If this method is succeeding for you what are you using to run this code?

Comment: I have just copy pasted your code within an empty console app and it works no problem.

Comment: @StfBln That's frustrating. I don't like that it works for you but not me. What Visual Studio version are you using?